# PHP check if date and time has passed 15 minutes

Tags: php, date

I'm having some trouble calculating if time is past 15 minutes, on a date and time in my database. How can I check this?

I have this in my database (example):

```
2014-01-30 15:29:31
```

And then I get the date from PHP:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But how can I check if the time has passed 15 minutes, or if it's a different day?

I have this code so far:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "SELECT date FROM reset WHERE session_id = '".$sessid."' limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$dbdate = $value->date;

$checkdate = strtotime($dbdate);
if ($checkdate - time() > 15 * 60) {
    error_log("15 mins passed");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a database ... you should just store this in the users session variable

Comment: Because it's a password reset link, after 15 minutes the row will be set as expired. That's why I'm using a database.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can convert the date to a timestamp with [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime) (which [supports](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) the MySQL date format) and then compare it to the current timestamp from [`time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time).

```
$dbtimestamp = strtotime($datefromdb);
if (time() - $dbtimestamp > 15 * 60) {
    // 15 mins has passed
}
```

To compare the dates, you can use [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date) to get the year/month/day from the timestamp and then compare them against the current date.

```
if (date("Y-m-d", $dbtimestamp) != date("Y-m-d")) {
    // different date
}
```

Comment: I don't think the time works. Look at the thread, I've updated it.

Comment: Also just tried the date, for some reason it gives me this date '1969-12-31'.

Comment: @Anders I just fixed a typo in the variable name, in case you copy-pasted my code.

Answer (score 4):

Using a DateTime object:

```
$dateTimeObject = new \DateTime($dateString);
//and subtract using an interval
$dateTimeObject->sub(new \DateInterval("PT15M"));
$newDateString = $dateTimeObject->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 2):

you cans use [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) functions.

```
$actual_minute = date("i");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%i') minutes FROM reset WHERE session_id = '".$sessid."'");
$database_minute = $data{'minutes'};
```